# Macro To Choose "Don't Save" on pop-up window (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

I was wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to choose "Don't Save" when an alert comes up. I'm talking specifically about Photoshop but the same action happens in many applications.

It's the standard pop up that shows when you are canceling out of a window and haven't saved the document or project. To be clear it says "Don't Save", "Cancel" and "Save". Save is generally the default but I was just curious if there's a way to choose "Don't Save" without clicking.

I know this may be a pretty simple question but I was curious about it and it's surprisingly hard to Google...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too sure about on OS X, but on Windows, sometimes there are underlined letters in the choices which are the keys you can press to choose them. Hopefully that might help in your situation.

Edit: I found [this](http://www.cultofmac.com/108494/use-the-new-cancel-dont-save-keyboard-shortcut-in-lion-os-x-tips/) post about your query. Command+Delete.

Comment: Perfect, that post was the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks!